# Best method for a generic web applications 'features' / global properties

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, web-config, generic-programming, n-tier-architecture

I'm creating a generic flexible site that I can use over and over again but with different features activated or deactivated. I'm looking for the best method to approach my solution.

Specific areas will need to be closed off in certain circumstances, for instance, the application will contain an event management page, but it will not always be required. The application will pull out the active and deactivated features from a data source.

They're going to be like Application wide settings, that will be required on each page, hiding away those settings that are turned off from the menu and not allowing users to access the deactivated feature pages.

I have thought of a number of ways to achieve this :

1. Store the feature statuses in the database, then on each time the page / menu is accessed / displayed, call the database requesting whether to hide the page / menu item.
2. Store the feature statuses in the database and access them on the application startup, store them application wide then they can be accessed as and when.
3. Put the feature statuses in the web config, this way we don't need to query the database every single time or have globally accessible properties.

I would like you advice on which method would be best, or if a better method is available I would be grateful. I don't want to hit the database too many times, or would a simple check like this not be too performance expensive? I'm also not sure if the web config is secure enough for managing active site features.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think putting configuration in configuration file(web.config) would be better option. Because while displaying page/loading menu going to database every time to see whether it should be de/active, required database trip which is overhead.

And if the configuration is stored in web.config it is easily accessible by admin and also easy to modify without compiling or changing anything.

So, in my view best option is to store configuration in web.config. In addition to that you can also make administration page which will change configuration settings and should be reflected in configuration file.

Comment: I wouldn't need to compile with the other 2 methods. And I would need to change something, there would be as much change as the other methods.

Comment: Is it possible to alter values in the web.config via an administration page?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest 2nd approach - store the settings in the database and then retrieve them at startup and store in application scoped containers.

The advantage of such approach over the `web.config` is that you can easily take client database and immediately run it in your development environment for testing/debugging. If, on the other hand, some settings are stored outside of the database, cloning the site means that you not only have to clone the database but also all the settings from various other resources (like the `web.config`).

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your answer. Although I would have to clone the web.config either way (it has the connection string in it).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how often you will be changing the status of the features.

If you are going to only set the statuses once when you clone the site and will never touch it again, go with option #2 (load on application start).

If there is any possibility that you will need to change the status of the features in the future, go with option #1 (get statuses on each page load). A simple datareader read to the db will not affect the speed of your site. The db is your friend, remember that's what it is there for. Also, if you ever need to change the statuses while the site is up and running, this method allows you to do so without restarting the entire application.

Whatever method you finally decide to implement, make sure the *"application wide"* location you store the settings is multi-threaded ready. Remember, each page request will be run on a separate thread and they will all access the same resource.

My suggestion taken from MS ([multi-thread safe Singleton Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)):

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```